# MPI: Segmentation fault in Master Slave Program

Tags: c++, mpi, mpich

Following is a simple program where all Slaves process sends a message to the Master process.

The program when executed runs correctly sometimes and raises `Segmentation Fault`the others.

```
int token;

if(rank == 0)
{
    for (int irank = 1; irank < world_size; irank++)
    {
        MPI_Recv(&token, 1, MPI_INT, irank, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
        cout << "Master: Token = " << token << endl;
    }
}


if(rank != 0)
{
    token = 1;
    cout << "Slave: Token = " << token << endl;
    MPI_Send(&token, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
}
```

[Full code here](https://gist.github.com/jainlashit/766bbe3503f315234bbad77867b6d160#file-gather-cpp)

Following is the error message:

```
YOUR APPLICATION TERMINATED WITH THE EXIT STRING: Segmentation fault:
11 (signal 11) This typically refers to a problem with your
application. Please see the FAQ page for debugging suggestions
```

[Full Error here](https://gist.github.com/jainlashit/766bbe3503f315234bbad77867b6d160#file-gather-err)

Why does this happen? Is this due to communication latency? If yes, how do I resolve it?

Comment: Fwiw, you can use `MPI_Gather()` to retrieve all the slave tokens on master.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet Sure! I'll try that but I really wanted to know what's wrong with my approach.

Comment: You appear to be ignoring end of stream and all errors, and assuming everything worked just dandy.

Comment: @EJP Shouldn't MPI handle such errors?

Comment: at first glance, i do not see any errors. are you able to get a stacktrace from a core file ?

Comment: note token is initialized on master but not on slave. since master receive and slaves send, that should be the other way around. i noted your program is called `bcast` but as written, it is a `gather`, so you might consider swapping the `MPI_Send()` and `MPI_Recv()` lines. that does not explain the random crashes though.

Comment: Yes, I had MPI_Bcast calls in my original program but to make the conflicting part more visible, I removed it. I'll update the token part but I think it doesn't matter.

Comment: to be on the safe side, can you replace `for (int rank = 1; rank < world_size; rank++)` with an other variable name since `rank` is used earlier) ? what about a stack trace ?

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE] in the question itself.

Comment: @tambre I've provided the link for better presentation since copy-pasting the whole code would be meaningless as it's filled with irrelevant junk.

Comment: which MPI version are you running ? did you install it via `brew` or something similar ?

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet I'm using MPICH. I installed it using their tar file that they provide.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet I've changed `rank` in the for loop to `irank`.  Regarding, stacktrace..can you guide me how to generate it? Thanks.

Comment: Here is a good [summary of debugging MPI](http://www.open-mpi.de/faq/?category=debugging). Most parts should be applicable even if it's written for a different implementation. Try running a simple hello world without send/recv. Your code should be fine.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet Even MPI_Gather didn't do the trick. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46515831/mpi-gather-segmentation-fault-in-master-slave-program

Comment: I think you should use a do loop to send the message from the rank 0 to all the other cpus.