# MPI_Gather: Segmentation fault in Master Slave Program

Tags: c++, mpi, mpich

Following is a simple program where all Slaves process send their rank (as the token) to the Master process.

The program when executed runs correctly most of the times but raises `Segmentation Fault` the others.

```
int token = rank;
vector<int> recvData(world_size);

MPI_Gather(&token, 1, MPI_INT, &recvData[0], 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

if(rank == 0)
{
    // Root process
    for (int irank = 1; irank < world_size; irank++)
    {
        cout << "Token received from rank " << irank << " = " << recvData[irank] << endl;
    }
}
```

[Full code here](https://gist.github.com/jainlashit/0f6725962574016b760ad706302d3139#file-gather-cpp)

Following is the error message:

```
YOUR APPLICATION TERMINATED WITH THE EXIT STRING: Segmentation fault:
11 (signal 11) This typically refers to a problem with your
application. Please see the FAQ page for debugging suggestions
```

[Full Error here](https://gist.github.com/jainlashit/0f6725962574016b760ad706302d3139#file-gather-err)

Is there any way to avoid such situations?

**Edit 1:**
Following are the outputs of `mpirun` when ran in verbose mode (both cases):

i) [Success Case](https://gist.github.com/jainlashit/05625dde5387f10462df70cfcef2846d)

ii) [Segmentation Fault Case](https://gist.github.com/jainlashit/05625dde5387f10462df70cfcef2846d#file-segfault-log)

P.S.: I asked a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46510891/mpi-segmentation-fault-in-master-slave-program) to this today, and a suggestion was given to use MPI_Gather() but the problem still persists.

Comment: Can you provide example inputs when it fails?

Comment: The program doesn't take any input. When I run `mpirun -np 4 ./gather` (say) it raises error sometimes.

Comment: I was thinking of number of processors when I said input.

Comment: I've checked it for many, the error prevails across all.

Comment: How often do you get it? I've checked for a couple: 4, 10, and 50. No error. I'll keep on running.

Comment: It's quite frequent for me. I would say 1 out of 3 times.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155722/discussion-between-lashit-jain-and-atru).

Comment: I don't know if you saw it in the discussion - try running after commenting out the three lines related to processor name.

Comment: i was unable to reproduce it on my mac. you can run `otool -L gather` and `which mpirun` to double check you are using the library you expect. `mpicc -E gather.c` will also help you figuring out whether you use the right headers. i am starting to think your mpich might be busted. could you for example try mpich provided by `brew` and see how things go ?

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet I've checked it's fine. The main problem is that it runs fine sometimes and fails the others. So the success case indicates there is nothing wrong with the headers. Regarding `mpich`, yeah I think something is wrong with it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MPI: Segmentation fault in Master Slave Program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46510891/mpi-segmentation-fault-in-master-slave-program) - The code is fine, just like the other code. This is most likely the same issue with your MPI installation as the other question. (Yes, this code is better than the other code, but it doesn't matter for the segfault.)

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue, but I use custom (source code based) installation of MPI at macOS: http://www.owsiak.org/?p=3492 What system do you work with? Also, note that linking might be tricky here. Maybe you can play with malloc and drop C++ lib to make sure you don't have issue there.